# Open Partial View on click of Edit button of Kendo Grid

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

My grid has a `FileUpload` control in it. After successful upload of the file, I am displaying imported records.

On Edit button click I need to display a `PartialView`. There will be so many add edit functionality on that partial grid. On close of `PartialView`, main grid should refresh.

Please let me know how do we call `PartialView` from Kindo grid on click of edit button.

Comment: It'll be helpful if you could post a snippet of your code relevant to your issue

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/custom-popup-editor-52debd2ced8d) example blog post from Kendo. This will let you use custom popup editor for your grid. You can override the events for what to happen when this custom pop up is closed.

Also look at [this](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) excellent article by Brad Wilson about custom templates in asp.net mvc.

If it still do not meet your needs please elaborate your question and add some code.